# Doubt regarding formation of integral

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

I am going through a textbook in which the following was stated:

> $$\frac{d}{dq}B\big(k\ ;\ n\ ,\ q\big)=n {{n-1}\choose k}\times (1-q)^k q^{n-k-1}$$
>
> On integration, we get
>
> $$B\big(k\ ;\ n\ ,\ q\big)=n{n-1\choose k}\times \int_0^q(1-u)^ku^{n-k-1}du$$

---

This might seem too trivial, but I would like to properly understand how the integral in the second line was arrived at. Specifically, I want to know how the limits have been determined.

I know that as per the FTC, $$\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ F(q)=\int_a^qf(u)du $$$$\Rightarrow \frac{d}{dq}F(q)=f(q)$$

Does the FTC have a role to play here? It seems like there might be a connection but I can't really find it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're correct, they're just applying the fundamental theorem of calculus.

Remember that the FTC goes both ways.  In some books they call this "part 1" and "part 2" of the FTC.

Comment: The FTC allows for an arbitrary lower limit though. Why is $\int_0^q$ part of the computation then? Or could I have taken any value other than $0$ and still be correct?

Comment: Changing the lower limit would change the value of the integral by a constant.  I don't know the context here, but taking the lower limit as zero is the choice that makes $B(k; n, 0) = 0$.  If that's desirable in this situation then that explains it.  Alternatively, it's possible that it just doesn't matter because they don't care about the actual value, just that the function has the given derivative.

Comment: You're right. The steps in my question are part of a proof where the final result involves the incomplete Beta Integral. So, choosing zero out of all possible lower limits is quite deliberate and purposeful.